# Jersey + Jackson + JAXB + @OneToMany relationships

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson, one-to-many, jersey-2.0

sup errbody,

i use JERSEY as JAX-RS WS, got jackson for JSON and using JAXB annotations to XML . spring for autowiring and hibernate as orm.

spring is 4.0.5
hibernate 4.2.13FINAL

i got my entities with @xmlrootelement annotation, jacksonfeature is registered, @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to avoid infinity recursion in all @onetomany and @manytoone.. and this just works when retrieving no-relationship entities.

for example, got the User entity very simple with login,password only... i can retrieve a list of users both xml and json in ajax call

this is my pom for jersey dependencies :

```
    <!-- Jersey RESTful -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>            
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>          
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Jersey RESTful -->
```

my resource method :

```
    @GET
    @Path("processo/{processo}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Processo infoProcesso(@PathParam("processo") String processo){
        return processoService.getProcesso(processo);
    }
```

code snippet from Processo entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "processo")
public class Processo {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  .
  .
  .
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="processo")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private List<Prioridade> prioridades = new ArrayList<Prioridade>();
}
```

code snippet from Prioridade entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "prioridade")
public class Prioridade {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JsonBackReference
   private Processo processo;
}
```

When retrieving @onetomany relationship entities, i can see the SQL statement in tomcat console, but if i try to use println before return it, it doesnt show up( it may be some configuration issue, still didnt set log4j or other).

with that said, when i run this ajax call from a local webserver ( miniweb ) :

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",    
url:"https://localhost:8443/pushrpi/processo/816101680",
dataType:"xml",
crossDomain: true,
headers: {
 "Authorization": "Basic ZGVwb3NlY2xpZW50OmRlcG9zZWNsaWVudA=="
}
}).done(function(data){alert('1');});
```

i get the OPTIONS response OK, but the GET is getting always (canceled) using chrome's dev tools.

Any other information you need? i dont get errors, warnings.. nothing back in tomcat console, the last "log" is the SQL statement.

any tips?

thanks in advance.
/fferrandini